# Is there any max inventory and management in the wastes?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Sending dwellers into the wastes to explore, and I find they stop finding items after 13. Is there a maximum capacity for explorers, and any way to get them to drop low-value items while they are out there?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Dwellers will find items every hour in the wastes, plus some time fixed events such as: Broadcast Tower, National Guard, etc.

However, their inventory do have a limit of 100 items. After picking 100 items, they won't pickup anymore, although they show up in the log that they have found something.

SPECIALS do affect the chance of finding items and caps. And their level will increase their HP.

Currently as of update <strike>1.03</strike> 1.1, there's no way to sell or ignore items while exploring

Please refer to the community spread sheet: [Fallout Shelter Efficiency Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nai09D_aM2syl3iPP5hkveDcOUwhsoUDR6s1lwC0e8c/edit#gid=1591448540).

SOURCE: [REDDIT](http://www.reddit.com/r/foshelter/comments/3a0p7v/room_efficiency_data_thread/)

Comment: Great answer. As of this morning, when a dweller is waiting outside to be Collected, you can tap items to convert them to coins rather than having the dweller bring them in -- makes it easier to manage inventory without having a ton of warehouses.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so. I have dweller returning at the moment with over 70 items. He has been out exploring for nearly 4 days.

The longer a dweller is exploring, the better the loot that they find. Increasing the level of the dweller increases the amount of hp that dweller has, meaning they can stay in the wastelands longer.

Comment: You're largely right. Wastelanders don't have a carry limit. I'd +1 you if you removed that bit about strength maybe playing a role

Comment: @Dallium the limit to carry is 100 items, you get 1 item every hour.. After 100 hours they wont pickup anything

Comment: @feco You could add this as your own answer. We don't mind seeing competing answers as we can vote up the most useful ones (note the plural).

Comment: @feco I agree with DJ Pirtu

Answer (score 0):

As Erhardt de Kock said, in 1.3 it seems that the carrying capacity of dwellers has been drastically lowered. I'm sending out people  who have max stats and they keep coming back with next to nothing without giving them a chance to explore. As far as I know, sending out more dwellers does not affect how much one dweller can carry. Strength affects what types of monsters they'll attempt to fight (and possibly kill, not sure), while Perception and Luck can increase item drops. That's about all I know.

Answer (score 0):

Some are saying 100 items, that seems right. Just today got a message from an Explorer just over Three Days out, "Well that's as much as I can carry, better report back to the Overseer." He automatically started coming back, and the Explore Button is Greyed out. I counted 104 items, but it's probably 100.

Comment: You are confirming that it's both "100" and "over 100". Which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if its still relevant. But my dweller returned automatically to the vault after collecting 104 items. Still 11 stimpacks left en 24 rads en couldnt carry anymore items.

Exploring was just over 3 days. This dweller had 8 strenght, 8 endurance and 11 luck. Had and -49% damage reduction pet.