# Dwellers in the wasteland always get no more than 1 item found?

Tags: fallout-shelter

In Fallout Shelter, when I send a dweller out to explore the wasteland he or she always finds an item within the first two hours, then simply doesn't find anymore items. The message log is normal and continues to indicate the dweller is finding caps and earning experience.

Even after 12 hours of exploring he has only had the one item from the first 2 hours. This isn't just bad luck because my dweller has 17 luck (lucky formal wear) and I have consistently never found more than one item during exploration.

[image http://s28.postimg.org/p3nutwvfg/image.jpg](http://s28.postimg.org/p3nutwvfg/image.jpg)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is a duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/227729/is-there-any-max-inventory-and-management-in-the-wastes

Comment: 12 hours?  I leave them out for days.  At least 3.

Comment: @CreeperzEdge: Unless I'm reading this wrong, I disagree: This asks why there is only 1 item found in 12+ hours, 227729 asks why his dwellers can't hold more than [13] items.

Comment: My friend and I did a test, we both sent out a dweller for 12 hours, his one found 13 and mine got 1 again :/. his dweller had 2 luck when mine had 17 again.

Comment: what about the rest of the stats?

Comment: He has max other stats (Strength,Agility,etc).

Comment: Wait Nelson, when you say you leave your dwellers out for at least 3 days, how much loot items do you get?

Comment: I found the solution for the problem, I started a new vault and it worked, I have been getting a ton of loot now.

Comment: I started the new vault to check if it was just my vault with the glitch, and it was, when I went back to my original vault it was fixed

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly a bug in the game. I've had hundreds of dwellers go out with widely varied skills (and definitely not max luck) and they have always come back with multiple weapons, even if they've only been out for a few hours.

I'd try hard-resetting your device to see if that clears it up. I've had other bugs in the game that were fixed this way. If it doesn't, I'd file a report with the developer.